# How to put the Discord.js token outside of code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I trying to build a discord bot with nodejs. I made it and want to push it to github. But I dont want that the token be visible in code because of security risks.
Is there a way of putting the token in a somewhere out of code and use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `.env` file that you add to your `.gitignore`, and add a `.env.template` file with the name of the variable so consumers would see what variables they need to set in the `.env` file (this file would be commited as an example). You will read that `.env` file by using a package such as [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

You can read more about this in articles such as [this one](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786).

Comment: Really Thank you. I had heard about dotenv before.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a `config.json` file put your token in it like :

```
{token:"token"}
```

Put it in your `.gitignore`
And in your main file import it:

```js
const {token} = require("./config.json")
```

Comment: Oh, this is a very straightforward way. It's simple. But i think it's better to make a config.example. I used it. Thanks bro